# While loop files in folder

Tags: while-loop, gis, netlogo

I'm relatively new to Netlogo and already struggling ;)
I have the following problem: I want my program to open a folder, check a file in that folder and afterwards remove that file from that folder. I figured the best way to do this is via a while loop, but I'm struggling to find the right syntax. Hope you all can help!

Comment: can you show us your current syntax (and whatever error message you get)?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more precise terms? What does "open a folder" mean? And what does "check a file" mean? Both of those phrases could mean many different things.

Answer (score 2):

The command 'file-open' will open a file using the path provided (the string after file-open: e.g. file-open "C:\Documents\model-out.txt" will open a file titled model-out.txt in the Documents folder on the C drive.)
You can then use 'file-read' or 'file-write' to read or write to the file respectively.
The command 'file-close' will close the file, which then can be deleted with 'file-delete'.
You can also check if a file exists in a folder using the command if file-exists? "C:\Documents\model-out.txt", and if true, the file can be deleted using file-delete.
Also check the command 'set-current-directory'.
Best,